# Depth First Search with backtracking in Java

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am trying to write a DFS to search the following weighted graph:

```
   0       1.       2.       3      4.     5.     6.      7.     8.   
0: 0.0,   0.68,   78.926,  6.205, 6.707, 48.45,  0.59,  0.704, 0.978, 
1: 1.47,  0.0,    116.021, 9.129, 9.869, 71.284, 0.869, 1.09,  1.44, 
2: 0.012, 0.0086, 0.0,     0.079, 0.085, 0.615,  0.007, 0.009, 0.012, 
3: 0.161, 0.109,  12.65,   0.0,   1.081, 7.807,  0.095, 0.119, 0.171, 
4: 0.149, 0.101,  11.764,  0.925, 0.0,   7.225,  0.088, 0.111, 0.146, 
5: 0.020, 0.014,  1.63,    0.128, 0.134, 0.0,    0.012, 0.015, 0.02, 
6: 1.69,  1.15,   142.86,  10.53, 11.36, 83.33   0.0,   1.254, 1.656, 
7: 1.42,  0.917,  111.11,  8.403, 9.01,  66.667, 0.797, 0.0,   1.321, 
8: 1.022, 0.69,   83.33,   5.848, 6.849, 50.0,   0.604, 0.757, 0.0,
```

I got this DFS code from the corsera tutorial on java graphs. what I thought it would do is find a path through a graph from one node to another--but it just gets stuck and just keeps adding nodes to the stack over and over again until it breaks.

How would I alter this code to instead check for a path from source to target where the product go edge weights is greater than 1.0? I'm sort of stuck...

DFS

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> find(final GraphAdjMatrix adjMatrix, int source, int goal) {

    stack = new Stack<>();
    this.visited = new HashSet<>();
    this.parentMap = new HashMap<>();

    stack.push(source);
    visited.add(source);

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        int curr = stack.pop();

        if (curr == goal)
            return parentMap;

        for (int n : adjMatrix.getNeighbors(curr)) {
            visited.add(n);
            parentMap.put(n, curr);
            stack.push(n);
        }
    }
    return parentMap;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, interesting but... it would be good if you put an example with a picture of tree backtracking (obviously not all nodes, only a section for have an idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test as I don't have the `GraphAdjMatrix` class, but I believe the problem is that the nodes are added to `visit`, but there is no check to see if a node was already visited. Try as follows:

public Map find(final GraphAdjMatrix adjMatrix, int source, int goal) {

```
stack = new Stack<>();
this.visited = new HashSet<>();
this.parentMap = new HashMap<>();

stack.push(source);
visited.add(source);

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    int curr = stack.pop();

    if (curr == goal)
        return parentMap;

    for (int n : adjMatrix.getNeighbors(curr)) {
       if (! visited.contains(n)) {
         visited.add(n);
         parentMap.put(n, curr);
         stack.push(n);
       }
    }
}
return parentMap;
```

}